# Is there a way to find out the motor phases without opening up the motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Good day,
I am doing a group project and we have a hub motor that looks like it was rewired by the previous students. For this reason we cannot tell which phases are which. We need to get it working with an A B C phase output esc. Would it be possible to find out which phases are a b and c by using a multimeter and turning the wheel? Or perhaps connecting the phases and seeing where the resistance is?[image]

Update: We were lucky to find a teacher who specializes in electric motors and ESCs. We just had to try the phases in whatever order and swap two if it wasn't running right.

Comment: How many wires are there? 3 or 6? Is it an induction motor or a BLDC?

Comment: Sounds like a bldc. Does it have hall sensors for commutation? Or just the motor phase wires? Maybe you should post a picture.

Comment: It's a BLDC motor with 3 phases and a hall sensor

Comment: The fat wires are phase wires. The skinny wires are hall sensor wires. Most likely the color code matches phase for phase. The red sensor wire tells you when to energize the red phase. Etc. The extra wires are power and ground (probably 3.3V or 5V).

Answer (score 2):

"*We were lucky to find a teacher who specializes in electric motors and ESCs. We just had to try the phases in whatever order and swap two if it wasn't running right.*" See if there's a better teacher! The phases not only have to be in the right sequence, they also have to match the Hall sensors which tell the ESC when to switch and which to switch. You have more work to do.

Fortunately there are matching sensor wires colours for each phase colour so try:

- Connect the three motor phases red, blue, green/yellow to phase A, B, C on the ESC.
- Connect the three Hall sensor outputs red, blue - and then you have a choice to make between the green and yellow - to Hall a, b, c on the ESC.
- The remaining two will be the Hall sensor power feed. You're going to have to do some exploring with these without damaging them.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this soon!